# Using awk/nawk, how to find out max and min contributions and printout those values?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

Using awk/nawk, how can I find max and min contributions and print those values?

Input file:

```
Name: Phone:1st:2nd:3rd contribution
Mike Harrington:(xxx) xxx-xxxx:250:100:175
Christian Dobbins:(xxx) xxx-xxxx:155:350:201
Susan Dalsass:(xxx) xxx-xxxx:280:60:50
Archie McNichol:(xxx) xxx-xxxx:250:100:175
```

Expected results would be max = $350 and min = $50

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
awk -F: '
    NR>1{
        for (i=3; i<NF+1; i++) {
            if ($i > max) {
                max=$i
            }
            else if ($i < min || min == 0) {
                min=$i
            }
        }
    }
    END{
        print "max = $" max " and min = $" min
    }
' file.txt
```

Comment: Edited script to output exactly like you wanted.